# Why doesn't my jQuery accordion work?

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

My accordion isn't working.  I checked to make sure I'm sourcing the correct js file along with google's jQuery UI.  Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

http://amandapampena.com/anthonys/anthonys_menu

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.min.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion'

Comment: Post the code here so that it will be helpful to others who have this problem in the future.

Comment: The FIRST thing you should be doing is checking for any errors in the log.

Answer (score 6):

You need to load jQuery first and then the plugins associated with it..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Change the order in which you load.. As jQuery UI is built using jQuery , It won;t recognize if the former is loaded after former

Answer (score 2):

You're loading jQuery-Ui before jQuery itself. Change the order to fix the error.